# update fetched form value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the user details. When clicking on update button, a modal is shown which contains a form. The form is initialised with the values of the user fetched form MySQL database.
The update query for the same is:

```
    <?php
    require('config.php');
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $conn->query("UPDATE `warehouse` SET `name`='$name',`address`='$address',`phone`='$phone',`email`='$email' WHERE `warehouse`.`id`='$id'");
   if(mysqli_affected_)
    header("Location: warehouse.php");
   }

   $members = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `warehouse` WHERE `id`='$id'");
    $mem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($members);
   ?>
```

The form is:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="modal.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $mem['name'];?>" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="address">Address:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <textarea name="address" rows="8" cols="55" required><?php echo $mem['address'];?></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone" class="control-label col-sm-2">Phone No.:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control"value="<?php echo $mem['phone'];?>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label col-sm-2">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $mem['email'];?>" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

On clicking submit button, i want to update the database with the updated value. But i am not being able to update the rows.

Comment: is there any  error ?

Comment: Becuase the form is in modal is not update as you are using. you have to use ajax for this. Have A Fresh Look at https://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-add-edit-modal-window/

Comment: Where is your `form` and `update` code located?

Comment: You could echo your update query and see if it contains what you expect.

Comment: See about prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting `$id` from `$_GET` request so you also have to set it in the form `action` too. By assuming that your `form` and `update` code is in the `model.php`  I have updated this `form` action

Change action of form as below

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="modal.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post">
```

It should work. If problem remains there kindly tell me